# File handling in Django when posting image from service call

Tags: python, django, apache-flex, pyamf

I am using [PyAMF](http://pyamf.org/) to transfer a dynamically generated large image from Flex to Django.
On the Django side i receive the encodedb64 data as a parameter:

My Item model as an imagefield.
What i have trouble to do is saving the data as the File Django Field.

```
def save_item(request, uname, data):
    """ Save a new item """    
    item = Item()

    img = cStringIO.StringIO()
    img.write(base64.b64decode(data))
    myFile = File(img)

   item.preview.save('fakename.jpg', myFile, save=False)
```

That would not work because my File object from StringIO misses some properties such as mode, name etc.

I also think that using StringIO will load the image data completely in memory which is bad so i may just give up on the AMF for this particular case and use POST.

What do you think ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In `django.core.files.base` you can find the class `ContentFile`. That class extends the basic Django `File` class, so you do not need StringIO (which ContentFile though uses internally). The modified save method looks like this:

```
from django.core.files.base import ContentFile
def save_item(request, uname, data):
    item = Item()
    myFile = ContentFile(base64.b64decode(data))
    item.preview.save('fakename.jpg', myFile, save=False)
```